# Change UICollectionView cell size with custom Flow Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have five rows of cells each row containing four cells - 5x4. I am trying to accomplish almost an Apple watch like effect. The row in the center of the screen should have cell sizes of 100x100 and the rest return sizes of 80x80. When scrolled, the row moving away from the center should turn to 80x80 and the row moving into the center should turn 100x100.

I have implemented `prepareLayout`, `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`, and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`

So right now I have a center row of 100x100 cells and the rest 80x80.
To make it dynamic I implement `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` but nothing happens.

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds{

     NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.layoutInfo.count];

     [self.layoutInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *elementIdentifier,
                                                     NSDictionary *elementsInfo,
                                                     BOOL *stop) {
          [elementsInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath,
                                                      UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes,
                                                      BOOL *innerStop) {
        //     NSLog(@"%f, %f", newBounds.origin.x, newBounds.origin.y);

             if ((newBounds.origin.y < [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height/2-50) && (newBounds.origin.y > [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height/2+50)) {
                 CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
                 frame.size.width = 100.0f;
                 frame.size.height = 100.0f;
                 attributes.frame = frame;
             }else{
                 CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
                 frame.size.width = 80.0f;
                 frame.size.height = 80.0f;
                 attributes.frame = frame;
             }
             [allAttributes addObject:attributes];
         }];
     }];

     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` is called pretty frequently (whenever the view is resized, or scrolled...), so you probably don't need to be doing all that work there.  If you know your cells will always have a fixed size and position then you can just return `NO` here.

As long as you have implemented `prepareLayout`, `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`, and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`, then make sure you also implement `collectionViewContentSize` to return the total size of the content.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not make it clear. When the `collectionView` loads the center will be 100x100, the rest 80x80. But, when the user scrolls, the once centered row will then turn to 80x80 if it moves aways from the center and the row moving into the center will turn to 100x100

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish with `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` but the cells remain their initial size.